# How to set up SSL for container website in my condition (Apache2)

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, containers, apache2

[The architecture of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkIkE.png)

I just want to know how upto set up SSL to change the HTTP to HTTPS in my situation. I have tried to follow a few guidelines but still failed…

Is there any detailed instruction/steps to guide me to set up SSL in such env?

I run all my things in apache2.

already have a domain name.

Any help will be appreciated… Many thanks...

Comment: Here you find a similar scenario: obtain a domain, register SSL certificate, run Docker, hope it helps. https://beppecatanese.medium.com/1-2-3-springboot-docker-nginx-digitalocean-1152ad7143ba

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

- Create `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` files with required keywords and commands (port forwarding, naming, images, etc.)
- Run a web server like Nginx or Apache
- Configure your domain(s) conf file(s)
- Install `certbot` in it for Let's Encrypt SSL for you domain
- Open your required port numbers in firewall if needed (if you firewall configured, you may not need this step)
- Run `docker-compose up -d --build`

**Long Answer**

`docker-file.yml` contents (read more in [Compose Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    ANY_NAME:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8201:8080
            - 8000:8101
    SECOND_NAME: # if you need more containers, copy this part
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - PORT_BE_ACCESSED_IN_WEB:LOCAL_PORT
volumes:
    SOME_NAME: {}
```

`Docekrfile` contents (read more in [Dockerfile Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)):

```
FROM nginx:latest # or any other base:version you need
# Your other commands goes there
# Example:
COPY ./domain.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN a2ensite domain
RUN service apache2 reload
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install certbot -y
RUN certbot ... # see certbot docs for more info
ENTRYPOINT ["some", "commands"]
```

Then run this command and if nothing goes wrong, it should be fine:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Now it should be accessible via `http://your_server_ip:8201` and `http://your_server_ip:8000`. If it's fine, then check `https://your_server_ip:8201` and `https://your_server_ip:8000`

Comment: Thanks for the ans. After trying out, I accidentally deleted etc/ssl file... what should i put in docker-file.yml volumes? and also, i use apache2 for both docker container and localhost. should i still use the first line "FROM nginx:latest"? and I used to install SSL with certbot but require manual installation. Under this condition, I still need to add "RUN certbot" ? Finally, what do you mean by some, command in ENTRYPOINT ["some", "commands"]?

Comment: Also, what is "cp ./domain.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/" for ?